# TensorFlow IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I have installed TensorFlow. When I download MNISTdataset, there exists one error. Who can tell me what's wrong? Thanks very much! The error detail as follows:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import input_data
>>> mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", False, False)
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "input_data.py", line 162, in read_data_sets
    local_file = maybe_download(TRAIN_LABELS, train_dir)
  File "input_data.py", line 22, in maybe_download
    filepath, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(SOURCE_URL + filename, filepath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 351, in open_http
    errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1202, in getreply
    response = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1127, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the site is still not accessible even after hours, you can modify the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py and change the source link to 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/lasagne/recipes/datasets/mnist/' and run the example again.

Answer (score 5):

Python was not able to download the MNIST dataset from lecun.com.  First, check to make sure you can browse [Yann LeCun's MNIST page](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) from that computer.  If you can't, it may be a firewall or Internet connectivity issue.  If you can, try running the download again in a few minutes - I've seen this error transiently a few times since the release of Tensorflow and it's always gone away within 5 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, I can not brouse Yann LeCun's MNIST page from that computer again, because I have one problem in Internet connectivity issue. Now, it works, thank you very much!

Comment: If the site goes down for a long time (it did for hours when I wanted it), a quick and dirty way would be to get MNIST dataset from somewhere else and copy the downloaded dataset directory containing *ubyte.gz files manually into your project root. 
Example:
`git clone https://github.com/HIPS/hypergrad && mv hypergrade/data/mnist YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT/MNIST_data && rm -rf hypergrad`

Answer (score 0):

As @user3851234 's answer, you can download the dataset by changing the `SOURCE_URL`, like:

```py
SOURCE_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/lasagne/recipes/datasets/mnist/'
```

There're few options for you:

- Offical source: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/
- Google mirror: https://storage.googleapis.com/cvdf-datasets/mnist/
- Amazon mirror: https://s3.amazonaws.com/lasagne/recipes/datasets/mnist/

---

**Special note for programmers in China**

The mirror provided by Google and Amazon often failed in Mainland China, you should try [Yann LeCun's page](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) first.

---

**Make your own MNIST mirror**

Preparation:

4 MNIST data files wherever you got:

- train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz:  training set images (9912422 bytes)
- train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz:  training set labels (28881 bytes)
- t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz:   test set images (1648877 bytes)
- t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz:   test set labels (4542 bytes)

and put them under your domain, like:

https://github.com/Amy/mnistrepo/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz

and change `SOURCE_URL` to your domain:

```py
SOURCE_URL = 'https://github.com/Amy/mnistrepo/mnist
```